# sending files through a network with python

Tags: python

I'm building a multi-agent system  with python, the first agent built a model and saved it in yaml file, it saved also the weights in hdf5 file, then it must send this 2 files to the second agent.
the files are saved in my pc, and the 2 agents also are in my pc.
how could the first agent send the 2 files to the second one?
thank you.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Perhaps with an example... and what have you already found online and tried?

Comment: the first agent built a model and save it in yaml file, it save also the weights in hdf5 file, then it must send this 2 files to the second agent.

Comment: Where exactly are the *agents* here? Where did the files get saved? Agent1 could save it to a location for Agent2 to read from. Or do they just run on separate threads? In which case you could look at using a `Queue` from the `queue` module.

Comment: the fikes will be saved im my own pc. the 2 agents are connected to localhost.

Comment: it's a master thesis project

Comment: I think you should try to add more information to your post (edit it... comments are not good because other people might not read them all). It would also be a good idea to describe how are you currently thinking of doing it. If it is all on your pc, why not just have a single directory that both agents know? Then you only need to let Agent2 know when a new pair of files has been written by Agent1, so it can then read them.

Comment: The reason you are being asked where the agents are, is to know what resources do they share. If they both have access to the same file system it is one situation - you can work with one file and take care of simultaneous access, e.g. via a lock. If they have access to shared memory, it's probably simpler/faster. If they are over a network, is it a TCP/IP network, what protocols do you have at your disposition, e.g. FTP, SSH,... or do you have any firewall limitations?

Comment: @mapto the agents are in my pc. I don't have any limitation

Comment: Please expand your question with the details you have shared with us. Also, to build on @n1k31t4's approach, you can have a process in Agent2 that periodically scans the shared directory for changes.

Comment: Do you expect to be simultaneously writing and reading to the files. If not, just [open the files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) normally from the second agent. Or maybe I am failing to see the challenge you're experiencing?

Comment: What does this have to do with data science? This seems more appropriate for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Since both agents are on the same computer, save both files to a directory. The second agent can read both files from the directory.